# how to get string in stringcontains c# in unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, unity-game-engine

can i get string from string contains? when i type "asdsahello1" how to get string on list only "hello1" in contains string.

```
public class FindContainsText : MonoBehaviour
{
private string[] test = { "hello1", "hello2" };
public Inputfield inputText;

void Update()
{
  foreach (string x in test)
    {
       if(inputText.Contains(x))
        {
        string getString;
        getString=//inputText.Contains(x) how?
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can use `for( int i=0 ; i<array.Length )` loop here. Given `if(true) break;`, `i` will be index you're looking for

Comment: It should probably be `inputText.Contains(x)` rather than `inputText.Contains.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
public class FindContainsText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string[] test = { "hello1", "hello2" };
    public InputField inputText;

    public void Update()
    {
        int matchIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inputText.text.Contains(test[i]))
            {
                matchIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchIndex != -1)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Input field contains {test[matchIndex]} (element number {matchIndex})");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider using [onValueChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html) event instead of Update. It gets called each time the Inputfield is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
getString=x;
```

Varible x contains value that you are testing.

Comment: x = hello1 and hello2

Comment: Ye, your string can conteins some your test strings e.g. "asdsahello1asdasdsahello2". And you can get all matches.